# What should I do my debian not booting up after sudden shutdown

Tags: linux, boot, debian, virtual-machine

I'm a windows user from last 15yrs. currently Expermenting debian in VM.

I want to learn linux and I think it's best to use it directly rather than VM.

I'm planning to switch to debian and have windows vm but I've experienced boot failures in debian after unexpected exit of my VM and I've no idea how to troubleshoot them as only 2 months old exp in linux.I plan to make debian as my daily driver and I got lot of power outages in my area which may cause boot failures. How should i handle this issue ?

Kindly help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Run Live Debian from USB, https://www.debian.org/CD/live/ , rather than install it. If the power fails, the USB is unaffected (unless you make it persistent).

Comment: Are you trying to repair your Debian, or find a more resilient way to use it in your particular circumstances? If you're trying to repair it, you'll need to tell us what IS showing on your screen when you boot the VM, the logs from the host, and any other data you have that may indicate the problem. Use the EDIT button to add this info to the question itself.